# Скроллбар не растягивается на всю высоту фрейма tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

Мой код:

```
canvas = Canvas(tab3, bg='yellow')
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
left_frame = Frame(canvas)
myscrollbar = Scrollbar(tab3, orient = 'vertical', command = canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = myscrollbar.set)
myscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=3)
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window = left_frame, anchor = 'nw')
def conf(event):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion = canvas.bbox('all'))
left_frame.bind('<Configure>', conf)
```

Что получается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы сколлбар растягивался, нужно при размещении указать, чтобы он должен растягиваться:

```
myscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="ns")
```

`sticky="ns"` означает прилипать к "северу" (north) и "югу" (south), т.е. к верху и низу ячейки.